# libx264 fails on HTTP Live Streaming (FFmpeg)

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, libx264

I want to live stream with `HTTP Live Streaming`, but I have problem with `libx264` or maybe something other.

My hardware and software environment:

- Macbook Pro
- VirtualBox with Ubuntu 16.04
- `Nginx` and `FFmpeg` (in Ubuntu)

I am able to stream a static video file (in Ubuntu with Nginx and FFmpeg). 
The `FFmpeg` command is as following:

```
$ffmpeg -i /my/sample/video.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -f hls /output/file.m3u8
```

But when it comes to webcam (live streaming), Mac OS Safari fails to open the stream. I used the following command:

```
$ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -codec:v libx264 -f hls /output/file.m3u8
```

I guess it's the problem of `libx264` because when I use `mpeg2video` encoder, Mac OS Safari indeed can play the stream:

```
$ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -codec:v mpeg2video -f hls /output/file.m3u8
```

I know there is a library called `video4linux2`, should I use video4linux2 for capturing my webcam? But I don't know the appropriate `FFmpeg` command for HTTP Live Streaming (I tried FFserver but there is error something like `cannot rename hls`)

anyone shed some light on my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out!

The reason why Mac OS Safari cannot open a HTTP Live Streaming encoded by `libx264` is because the default codec in Mac OS does not support the default output by `libx264`!

Simply add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to the `FFmpeg` command and everything works fine:

```
$ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /your/webcam/path -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p /output/file.m3u8
```